# How to change the state of a grandfather component from the grandson in React Native + TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to change the state of a component from the grandson, this is my 'grandfather' component (I don't put all the code because it is too long):

```
class ContentAccept extends Component {
     constructor (props: any) {
         super (props);
         this.state = {
             initialArray: []
         }
     }
```

'initialArray' is a list that I later add values to and such. What I want now is from the 'grandson' component to add or remove objects to the list. For that I understand that I have to create a function in the 'grandfather' component to modify the list, the first problem is that from a function it does not let me access the state, for example, if I add this function in the grandfather component, an error occurs :

```
Hi() {
         console.log (this.state.initialArray);
     }
```

Any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a callback function, and pass it as a prop to all of your descendants (which I do not recommend at all. See Context API for better practice). By doing so, the 'grandson' can call this function (in which you should use `setState` obviously).